# How to merge geoseries to geodataframe based on geometry attributes?

Tags: python, dataframe, merge, geopandas

I have 5868 points in a geodataframe with some columns/attributes. Between points which have distance less than 10 m, I just want to select only one point as representation in that area. I have done using the following code:

```py
ships = gpd.read_file(r"D:\Suhendra\Riset BARATA\data ais\lego_python\kepri_201812_ship.shp")
#'ships' have 5868 data/rows. It is geodataframe with some columns

#remove the 'ships' geometry that have less than 10 m distance each other
point_nodes = list(ships['geometry'])
for i in range(len(point_nodes) - 1):
    if point_nodes[i] is None:
        continue
    for j in range(i + 1, len(point_nodes)):
        if point_nodes[j] is None:
            continue
        if point_nodes[i].distance(point_nodes[j]) < 10: #in meter
            point_nodes[j] = None

new_point_nodes = gpd.GeoSeries([node for node in point_nodes if node is not None])
#'new_point_nodes' have 5321 data, it is just geoseries with geometry information
```

The result is 5321 points (reduced than the original data), but it is just geoseries not geodataframe like the original data. How to do the following condition in order to get the result like the original data?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of merging the result to your original DataFrame, I suggest you filter the original DataFrame based on your calculations. To this end, I suggest doing the distance comparisons on a pandas Series instead of a list. This retains the originals DataFrame's index, which again allows for easy filtering in the end

```
point_nodes = ships['geometry']

# Do distance comparisons on pandas Series instead of list
for i in range(len(point_nodes) - 1):
    if point_nodes.iloc[i] is None:
        continue
    for j in range(i + 1, len(point_nodes)):
        if point_nodes.iloc[j] is None:
            continue
        if point_nodes.iloc[i].distance(point_nodes.iloc[j]) < d:
            point_nodes.iloc[j] = None

# Now filter the original DataFrame according to point_nodes (select all elements which are not None in point_nodes)
new_point_nodes = ships.loc[~point_nodes.isnull()]
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. I have tried it, but the result was just 1 row. I don't know what the problem. Let me clarify my question.

Comment: As I used my own data for testing, maybe my modifications to the distance checking did not work for your data. I edited the answer such that the distance checking is more similar to your original code with nested loops (takes a bit longer though ;) )

Comment: Ok. I have already edited my question. It maybe more clarified and changes your thought?

Comment: have you tried running the edited code? new_point_nodes should be a GeoDataFrame without the rows which don't match your minimum distance criterium.

Comment: sorry @bexi, thank for your support for my problem. But I have fixed my problem with this solution https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/325699/133557.